# ADT: Packaging failed. Make sure your computer time is in sync and your certificate is valid

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.5

I use ant to build flex application and sign it with self generated certificate, it works fine for a long time with "Flex 4.6 & AIR 3.5"
Today I've tried the latest SDK "Flex 4.10 & AIR 3.9" but my build script doesn't work on OSX because of some problems with certificate:

```
[INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] [ant:java] Packaging failed. Make sure your computer time is in sync and your certificate is valid
```

In the same time it works with latest SDK on Windows.
I've tried to generate new certificate or use another OSX but result still the same.

Comment: Just tried with real certificate, the same error message :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. Using Flex 4.6 with AIR 3.9. It works on Windows but on OS X it gives the same error message

Comment: Same problem started occurring here as well.  Using Flash Builder 4.7 with AIRSDK 3.9 overlaid.  The problem was occurring with AIRSDK 3.8 also, so I upgraded, no no avail.  Prior to the error occuring, _nothing_ in my code or build script had changed since it last functioned.

Comment: This is very strange... I downgraded back to Flex 4.6 & Air 3.8 and it started working again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known issue with the AIR SDK.  I don't know why or how it suddenly stopped working for people, but the fix is to remove the  section from air app descriptor .xml file.

See this link for more info, and perhaps a heads-up when Adobe fix the problem for real.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1317862#5771096

Answer (score 2):

I received the same problem when I had 450MB video files included the project. The problem was the file size was too big. I left the video files out of the project and could successfully publish it. Then I put the video files into the project folders manually.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem re: filesize - even though the error message mentioned the time and certificate, the problem was definitely the addition of a giant 1GB+ asset in my build. removing it let the thing compile as usual.